# Average value from 2d space

Tags: c++, arduino, 2d, polygon

I'm currently working on a pice of software that interpolates data from existing measurements and makes estimates from this. The data is arranged in a 2D environment where we've got a wind speed on one axis and a wind angle on the other and each point represents a target speed.

For an example I've got three points: 
p1: wind speed 6 knots, wind angle 90 degrees => target speed 5
p2: wind speed 6 knots, wind angle 70 degrees => target speed 6
p3: wind speed 8 knots, wind angle 70 degrees => target speed 7

Now I want to interpolate the point of wind speed 6 knots and wind angle 80 degrees. I would like an algorithm that uses all of these points and gives me an average of these three points.

Ages ago I made a 3D renderer and I think I used a technique there to color a polygon and I think this can be useful in this scenario. All the examples that I've found on the internet rely on OpenGL and such and that won't work for me as I want this solution to be pure c/c++ for an embedded environment. Since i run in an embedded environment I've got limited resources mainly in terms of program size.

Do any of you guys have any pointers to help me get past this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm not asking for a complete solution, just a pointer to algorithms used to colorize a polygon.

Comment: check the answer and let me know if it helped or not.

Answer (score 1):

After diving into my old calculus i found a mathematical answer to this problem.

Given that I've got three points in the space I can form a plane:

```
P: (Px, Py, Pz)
Q: (Qx, Qy, Qz)
R: (Rx, Ry, Rz)
```

These points and the math described in here http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/EqnsOfPlanes.aspx allowed me to move forward.

```
Vector(PQ) = (PQx, PQy, PQz)
Vector(PR) = (PRx, PRy, PRz)
```

Now I apply the cross product to these two vectors and this gives the normal vector of the plane
(Cross product math described here: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/CrossProduct.aspx#Vectors_CrossProd_Ex2)

```
Vector(PQ) x Vector(PR) = Vector(PQy * PRz - PQz * PRy, 
                                 PQz * PRx - PQx * PRz,
                                 PQx * PRy - PQy * PRx)
```

So, this is what I've got as a plane equation, without respect to that it has to pass trough one of the points:

```
x(PQy * PRz - PQz * PRy) + y(PQz * PRx - PQx * PRz) + z(PQx * PRy - PQy * PRx) = 0
```

To get the full equation of my plane that passes trough all of the points, I have to apply one point, as described in example 1 in the first link.

```
x(PQy * PRz - PQz * PRy) + y(PQz * PRx - PQx * PRz) + z(PQx * PRy - PQy * PRx) = 
Px(PQy * PRz - PQz * PRy) + Py(PQz * PRx - PQx * PRz) + Pz(PQx * PRy - PQy * PRx)
```

---

To apply my example to this formula I get the following equation:

```
P: (90, 6, 5)
Q: (70, 6, 6)
R: (70, 8, 7)

Vector(PQ) = (20,  0, -1)
Vector(PR) = (20, -2, -2)
```

Cross product of these gives me this formula:

```
-2x + 20y - 40z = 0
```

If I now apply the point P to this I can get the full equatio of my plane:

```
-2x + 20y - 40z = -2 * 90 + 20 * 6 - 40 * 5
-2x + 20y - 40z = -260
z = (-2x + 20y + 260) / 40
```

As I seek the z value where x = 6 and y = 80 I put these values into the equation.

```
x = 80
y = 6
z = (-2 * 80 + 20 * 6 + 260) / 40
z = 5.5
```

5.5 is the expected answer for this example as it exactly in the middle of P and Q.

The final implementation of this algorithm:

```
float TargetSpeed::PlaneInterpolation(Point3D p, Point3D q, Point3D r, int x, int y)
{
    Point3D pq = Point3D(p.X - q.X, p.Y - q.Y, p.Z - q.Z);
    Point3D pr = Point3D(p.X - r.X, p.Y - r.Y, p.Z - r.Z);

    Point3D  n = Point3D(pq.Y * pr.Z - pq.Z * pr.Y, 
                         pq.Z * pr.X - pq.X * pr.Z, 
                         pq.X * pr.Y - pq.Y * pr.X);
    float d = n.X * p.X + n.Y * p.Y + n.Z * p.Z;

    float z = (d - n.X * (float)x - n.Y * (float)y) / n.Z;
    return z;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the data on a regular grid? If so, I would just use something like linear interpolation. If not, then look at something like qhull.

Comment: Yes, I'd say it is a regular grid. In the future I might be looking at a more complex interpolation but the linear interpolation with a 3d plane works for now. Thanks!